# Difference of Max and Min in a 2-D Array

Tags: java, max, min, absolute

Below is my program that attempts to find the absolute value of the difference between the max and minimum values inside a two-dimensional array. Unfortunately, I keep on receiving 1 as the answer, when it should be 12 (Math.abs(7-(-5)). My guess is that there is a simple error in the code that I am missing out on.

```
class Main
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[][] a = {
        {-5,-2,-3,7},
        {1,-5,-2,2},
        {1,-2,3,-4}
    };
    System.out.println(diffHiLo(a)); //should print 12
}

public static int diffHiLo(int[][] array)
{
    int max = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int min = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    for (int[] cool : array){
      for(int z: cool){
        if (z < min )
          min = z;
        else if (z > max)
          max = z;
      }
    }

    return Math.abs(max-min);    
  }
}
```

Comment: You initialize `max` and `min` backwards. Set `max = Integer.MIN_VALUE` and `min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;`

Answer (score 2):

You should initialize `min` to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and `max` to `Integer.MIN_VALUE`. You are doing the opposite, causing your loop to do nothing (since `z` is never smaller than `min` or larger than `max`).

The result you get is `1` because `min` and `max` are not changed by your loop and `Integer.MAX_VALUE-Integer.MIN_VALUE` is `-1` (due to numeric overflow).